# SQL - Find customers who bought all products

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Suppose I have 2 tables:

Table A

```
C_ID   P_ID
   1      1
   1      2
   2      1
```

Table B

```
P_ID
   1
   2
```

In Table A, `C_ID` and `P_ID` serve as PK, in Table B `P_ID` is the PK

I want to find all C_ID that bought all products in B (basically all P_ID in B). In the example above that would `C_ID = 1`

Can you check if below is correct? Any alternatives that are more efficient/easier?

```
SELECT A.C_ID
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.P_iD = B.P_ID
GROUP BY A.C_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT A.P_ID) >= (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT P_ID) FROM B)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your query seems correct. You need to replace `=` in place of `>=`.

Comment: @YogeshSharma oh that's right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

following query works with MySQL and SQL Server.

you can do this without `JOIN`

```
select 
    c_id
from tableA 
group by 
    c_id
having count(distinct p_id) = (select count(*) from tableB)
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for your feedback. I have added another solution without using `JOIN`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'd think a join would be needed as just because count(distinct A.p_id) = count(distinct B.p_Id) doesn't mean they are the same group of p_id, right? Like A1, A2, A3 vs, A1, A2, A4. The # is the same, but the content is different

Comment: @user12562215 No, you actually don't need that join, because the subquery on `tableB` is not correlated to the outer query.  +1 to this answer therefore.

Comment: @zealous I still think tableA and tableB need to be linked, otherwise the p_id could be totally different and just coincidentally have the same number

Comment: @user12562215 I respect your thoughts but you do not need to link those two tables at all.

Comment: @zealous Thanks. But in an extreme example, tableA has just one c_id with three p_id (say, A, B, C). So count(distinct p_id)  = 3. Then tableB also has 3 p_id (say, A, B, D), so the count(*) from tableB also is 3. Here 3 = 3 but that c_id never purchased B

Comment: @user12562215 You also need to understand the case where how can user have purchased product which does not exist in the product table, so in that condition your case totally `invalid`.

Comment: @zealous yeah that's true. This is an interview question I saw online. I guess in the real world, the product table could have different product types/groups, so the question would become: find customer who purchased all products from a certain prodcut type in the product table

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is not correct, as it only verifies that a customer bought as many distinct items as there are items in the product table. If however you table looked like this:

```
C_ID   P_ID
   1      1
   1      3
   2      1
```

the query would return customer 1 even though Customer 1 did not but all the products (namely, they did not buy product `P_ID=2`.

**Generalized Solution**

what you are looking for is called a division query. The strategy is based on a  double negation, think:

*"give me all the customers for which there is no product, that has never been purchased"*

in SQL:

```sql
-- define a customer table
WITH customers as (
     SELECT DISTINCT C_ID
     FROM A)

-- all customers who have not
SELECT * 
FROM customers as outer
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(   -- all products which have not
    SELECT * 
    FROM B as inner
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (   -- ever been purchased
        SELECT* 
        FROM A as matchtable
        WHERE matchtable.C_ID=outer.C_ID
        AND matchtable.P_ID=inner.P_ID)
 )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this relevant answer. And what about a relationship between 4 tables? @safex Have a look on my topic: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74922360/17783040